# not sure why NSFetchedResultsController isn't showing sections

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I previously had a TableView which would get its 2 header views (and separator views) from an array called `holdViewsArray` in viewDidLoad, like so:

-(void) viewDidLoad{

```
// ---Start Core Data With NSFetchedResultsController---
[super viewDidLoad];
NSError *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);
}
// ---End Core Data w/ NSFetchedResultsController---

[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
holdViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

UIView *seperatorView;
UIView *seperatorView2;

NSString *sectionTitle = @"Tasks To Complete";
NSString *section2Title = @"Completed Tasks";
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];

label.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 5.0, 320.0, 50.0);
label.text = sectionTitle;

label2.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 320.0, 40.0);
label2.text = section2Title;

headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:label.frame];
headerView2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:label2.frame];

CGRect sepFrame = CGRectMake(0, headerView.frame.size.height-2, 320, 1);
CGRect sep2Frame =CGRectMake(0, headerView2.frame.size.height-2, 320, 1);

seperatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame];
seperatorView2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:sep2Frame];

[headerView addSubview:seperatorView];
[headerView2 addSubview:seperatorView2];
[headerView addSubview:label];
[headerView addSubview:button];
[headerView2 addSubview:label2];
[holdViewsArray addObject:headerView];
[holdViewsArray addObject:headerView2];
```

}

After implementing `NSFetchedResultsController`, I decided that I wanted to use `NSFetchedResultsController's` properties and methods to make the header views and split the table view into 2 sections. I've tried to do so, but its not giving me any titles in my sections and it just looks awful. How would I keep the same look of the headers that I have now but use `NSFetchedResultsController` to split the table view into 2 sections (complete and incomplete tasks)? Here is what I tried:

**Tasks Core Data property (optional property):**

```
@interface Tasks : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sectionString;
@end

@implementation Tasks
@dynamic sectionString;
@end
```

**Adding two tasks in different sections in the App Delegate**

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSManagedObject *startingTask = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tasks" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [startingTask setValue:@"Eat Dinner" forKey:@"taskName"];
    [startingTask setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:400] forKey:@"timeInterval"];
    [startingTask setValue:@"Tasks To Complete" forKey:@"sectionString"];

     NSManagedObject *finishedTask = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tasks" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [finishedTask setValue:@"Do Laundry" forKey:@"taskName"];
    [finishedTask setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:400] forKey:@"timeInterval"];
    [finishedTask setValue:@"Completed Tasks" forKey:@"sectionString"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

**Splitting into two sections**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Tasks" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

 NSSortDescriptor *isCompleted = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"sectionString" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[isCompleted, sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionString"
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

What am I doing wrong that's causing it to not split into 2 sections with titles of "Tasks To Complete" and "Completed Tasks"?

Comment: Try `cacheName:nil` (there could be an old section cache).

Comment: Just tried it. The table view splits into 2 sections but there is nothing in the headers. just two empty blocks above the rows

Comment: Did you implement `titleForHeaderInSection`? Is it called? What string does it return?

Comment: Oh jk. It worked :). I accidentally commented out the viewForHeaderInSection

Comment: hmm...when there are no objects in the managedobjectcontext, the fetchedresultscontroller doesnt display a header. this is a problem because my add object button is on the first header. is there a way to make a section header show even if there are no objects in the section?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to "tweak" the table view data source methods and the FRC delegate methods. This question and answer might help as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761221/custom-cell-on-empty-table-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller.